# JS: Automatic scroll when mouse idle, finger not touching?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know people will complain I'm not showing code here, but I don't see much of value to post my Jquery/JS attempt. The only important part is that I 'd like to do it in a div

my divs are now like

```
#wrapper {overflow:hidden, width:100%; height:100%, position: absolute}
#content_inside_wrapper {width:100%; height:3000px}  //height is given, never auto
```

Essentially what I am trying to do and I need help with, is to have some JS code, that automatically scrolls `#content_inside_wrapper` vertically just in one direction (say from top to bottom) when a user doesn't interact with it, but then overwrite the auto-scroll when a user scrolls the mouse wheel or drag with fingers, AND then back to automatic when the mouse is idle again or the user stops touching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that works like a charm:

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

let timerId;

function initTimer() {
  timerId = setInterval(() => wrapper.scrollBy(0, 1), 50);
}
initTimer();

wrapper.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {clearInterval(timerId)}, {passive: true});
wrapper.addEventListener("touchend", initTimer, {passive: true});
```

```css
body {overflow: hidden;}
#wrapper {overflow-y: scroll; width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute}
#content_inside_wrapper {width:100%; height:3000px}
```

```html
<main id="wrapper">
<div id="content_inside_wrapper">Lorem<br>ipsum<br>dolor<br>sit<br>amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing<br>elit.<br>Suspendisse<br>faucibus<br>nibh<br>quis<br>posuere<br>lobortis.<br>Nulla<br>elementum<br>ex<br>consequat<br>orci<br>mattis<br>pulvinar.<br>Suspendisse<br>potenti.<br>Donec<br>consectetur,<br>justo<br>vel<br>mollis<br>porttitor,<br>magna<br>ex<br>suscipit<br>nisi,<br>viverra<br>mollis<br>ante<br>ipsum<br>non<br>arcu.<br>Aenean<br>egestas<br>arcu<br>quis<br>augue<br>ultrices,<br>at<br>mollis<br>nulla<br>vehicula.<br>Quisque<br>vel<br>ipsum<br>vitae<br>neque<br>efficitur<br>malesuada.<br>Nam<br>ac<br>tristique<br>urna.<br>Sed<br>a<br>lacus<br>id<br>augue<br>dapibus<br>venenatis<br>nec<br>scelerisque<br>magna.</div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is excellent. you interpreted my idea to the perfection...auto-scroll but back to user interaction when they need it. thank yo so much, i'd never been able to find this solution by myself!!

Comment: and it feels natural...unobtrusive... oh thank you again

Comment: and thinking about it could be even cool to reverse the direction one the users scroll in the opposite direction. I believe listening to the mouse-wheel direction I could do that...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on your issue: we can use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to perform the scrolling for you. The reason why I choose not to use `window.setTimeout()` or `window.setInterval()` is because it is not extremely reliable (subject to drift) as the exection of its callbacks are pushed to the end of the callstack. `window.requestAnimationFrame` will scroll your element once the browser is free to repaint again, hence optimizing performance.

Then, you can choose to interrupt the recursive calling of `window.requestAnimationFrame` when you detect a certain event (e.g. `mousewheel` or `touchend`), and then set a timeout to resume scrolling again.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
const scrollSpeedPerSecond = 150;
const scroller = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const timeToWaitBeforeResumeScrolling = 1000;
let previousTimestamp;
let allowScroll = true;

function scrollStep() {
  if (!previousTimestamp)
    previousTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
    
  const currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const elapsedTime = currentTimestamp - previousTimestamp;

  const scrollY = scrollSpeedPerSecond / 1000 * (currentTimestamp - previousTimestamp);

  scroller.scrollBy(0, scrollY);
  
  // Update previous timestamp, so we can diff the next "tick" and see how far we need to scroll on the next invocation
  previousTimestamp = new Date().getTime();

  // We want to only allow recursive calling of itself (basically like a setInterval, when:
  // 1. We have not scrolled to the end of the scroller
  // 2. The `allowScroll` flag is set to true
  if (
    // 1
    scroller.scrollTop < scroller.scrollHeight - scroller.clientHeight &&
    // 2
    allowScroll
  ) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollStep);
  }
}


// Call scrolling logic onload
window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollStep);

// Interrupt scrolling when certain events are detected
function pauseScrolling() {
  allowScroll = false;
  
  // After a fixed amount of time, we allow resuming of scrolling
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    allowScroll = true;
    previousTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollStep);
  }, timeToWaitBeforeResumeScrolling);
}

window.addEventListener('mousewheel', pauseScrolling);
document.addEventListener('touchend', pauseScrolling);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

#content_inside_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 98%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 98%),
    linear-gradient(0deg, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple);
  background-size: 100% 50px, 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content_inside_wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great and interesting observation about the SetInterval, but what i need is like @D. Pardal solution above, where the scroll doesn't stop UNESS the user scrolls, not hover

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution:

```js
ScrollRate = 100;

function scrollDiv_init() {
    DivElmnt = document.getElementById('content_inside_wrapper');
    ReachedMaxScroll = false;

    DivElmnt.scrollTop = 0;
    PreviousScrollTop = 0;

    ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}

function scrollDiv() {

    if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop++;

        ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
    }
    else {
        ReachedMaxScroll = (DivElmnt.scrollTop == 0) ? false : true;

        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop--;
    }
}

function pauseDiv() {
    clearInterval(ScrollInterval);
}

function resumeDiv() {
    PreviousScrollTop = DivElmnt.scrollTop;
    ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Auto Scroll</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body onLoad="scrollDiv_init()">
    <div id="content_inside_wrapper" style="overflow:auto;width:50%;height:100px" onMouseOver="pauseDiv()"
        onMouseOut="resumeDiv()">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Error provident suscipit cumque quaerat ex, quos neque modi iste.
            Quia veniam ipsa possimus expedita!
            Mollitia saepe repudiandae nobis dolorum expedita neque?</p>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this using a semaphore, which is set to green by default. If a scroll happens, then the semaphore is set to false (red), so. A recurring event would check for the semaphore. If it's true, then it would do the scroll and at the end of the event it would set the semaphore to true.

```
var semaphore = true;

setInterval(function() {
    if (semaphore) {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1);
    }
    semaphore = true;
}, 50);


window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    if (semaphore) semaphore = false;
});
```

You can handle touch events similarly.